# How to encode my data for logistic regression, RF and GBDT

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to perform logistic regression but I'm not sure how to encode the input. I already split the data.

My df has the following columns:

doc_no, personal_no, tokens (preprocessed texts using spacy), day and score

Data types:

```
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 
 0   doc_no       30363 non-null  int64 
 1   personal_no  30363 non-null  int64 
 2   tokens       30363 non-null  object
 3   day          30363 non-null  object
 4   score        30363 non-null  object
dtypes: int64(2), object(3)
```

The tokens look like a list of lists.
Day is as follows: MAY03, JUN05 etc.
Score is 0 or 1.

I want to predict **score** based on **tokens**.

I split the data:

```
columns = ['doc_no', 'personal_no', 'tokens', 'day', 'score']

df = df_new.loc[:, columns]

# arranging the data
features =  ['doc_no', 'personal_no', 'tokens', 'day']

X = df.loc[:, features]
y = df.loc[:, ['score']]

# train test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, 
                                                    train_size=0.8)
```

I know I need to vectorize the tokens, using TF-IDF I think? But that's not working so far. When I try to run this:

```
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "['word', 'word', 'word', 'word']
```

I changed the contents to 'word' because my data is privacy sensitive.

What do I do?

I also want to perform random forest and gradient boosted decision tree on this data. Would there be other things I need to take into account for those algorithms?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

TfidfVectorizer (I suppose you talk about the one from sklearn) works from texts. So if your text is already tokenized, you can't use that.

You can apply yourself the formula, which is simple enough, or you can do the following:

```
tokens = [" ".join(ts) for ts in tokens]
tfifd_scores = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(tokens)
```

NB: I assume that the tokens you get from spacy are different from those you'd get with sklearn. Otherwise, just skip the tokenization and work directly on your texts.

Comment: Now I get ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words

Comment: Can you show the contents of `tokens` (not all of it, just enough to get what happens)?